# Images not switching on mobile devices

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I have this little bit of jQuery that just switches an images and does some zooming...

```
    jQuery(".image-list-image").on('click', function(){

                // this line fixes my issue
                jQuery('.product-zoom-container').trigger('zoom.destroy');


                var org = jQuery('#main-image').attr("src");
                console.log('org = ' + org)

                var src = jQuery(this).attr("data-main-image-src");
                console.log('src = ' + src)
                if(src != org){
                    jQuery('#main-image').fadeOut(400, function(){
                        jQuery("#main-image").attr("src", src);
                    }).fadeIn(400);

                    jQuery('.product-zoom-container').zoom({
                        magnify: .25,
                        url: src,
                        on: 'grab',
                    });
                }
            });
```

It works perfectly in a desktop browser, but not on mobile devices, initially you can tap on each .image-list-element and it will swap the #main-image out just fine.  However if you grab on the main image the tap on .image-list-element stops working,  the container will resize to the size of the src image, but the actual image does not change.

I'm not sure what is going on here as to why it works on desktop & not mobile.

Can someone explain what is happening [and a fix]

**UPDATE**

added a link of script to destroy the zoom container before trying to do any further operations on it.  Seems to have fixed my issue

Comment: Can you post a jsfiddle or an example of your HTML?

Answer (score 0):

Solved my own problem - update added to question :)

```
// this line fixes my issue
jQuery('.product-zoom-container').trigger('zoom.destroy');
```